# How to reset a property in ANT?

Tags: ant, properties, velocity, reset

I'm writing a velocity macro within which I have some ant tasks. Within a #foreach loop in the velocity macro, I have a pathconvert task:

```
#foreach(<iterate through something>)        
        <pathconvert property='filename' refid='swf.file'>
          <mapper>
            <chainedmapper>
                <flattenmapper/>
                <globmapper from='*-d.swf' to='*'/>
            </chainedmapper>
          </mapper>
        </pathconvert>
#end
```

The problem I have is that the 'filename' property gets set only once, during the first iteration, since properties in ANT are immutable.
But I need the filename to be set during each iteration. Is there a way to get this done?

If there was a way to reset the property, I could do that at the end of each iteration. Or is there a better way to do this?
Any help would be highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance,
Anand

Answer (score 4):

You could use ant-contrib's variables.  They act like mutable properties.

http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/variable_task.html

Comment: yup this is what I use (and I suspect a lot of others too), also gives you if, try-catch, for loops etc etc

Answer (score 3):

Use the new lexically scoped properties in Ant 1.8:

"Lexically scoped local properties, i.e. properties that are only defined inside a target, sequential block or similar environment."

[Annoucement.](http://ant.apache.org/antnews.html)

Properties in Ant were designed to be immuatable, but they gave in to popular demand and gave us variables.  Your alternative is to write a custom task ( in Java or a Dynamic Language) but this seems like a good compromise.

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet illustrates an ant property which I guess is not documented. **Properties are immutable, but references are mutable**. So any data type which has no name, but a reference, is mutable. For example a `fileset`. But today I found a way to have a kind of mutable property. Connected with `local` task or some other tricks it may be a way of having variables in ant.

```
<property name="a" value="aaa" id="refa" />
<property name="b" refid="refa" />
<echo>${b}</echo>
<property name="c" value="ccc" id="refa" />
<property name="d" refid="refa" />
<echo>${d}</echo>
```

The output is:

```
aaa
ccc
```

Although in both cases a reference `refa` is printed.

Here is [a post about it](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/ant-dev/200311.mbox/%3cm365i1j126.fsf@bodewig.bost.de%3e). And [another one](http://ant.1045680.n5.nabble.com/quot-Overriding-previous-definition-of-reference-quot-should-I-worry-td1347799.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of for + let task from [**Ant Plugin Flaka**](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/) to overwrite existing properties.
See [some snippets here](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/wiki/FlakaExamples).